# Alternatives to the barplot function

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram, bar-chart

I have a doubt about the use of the barplot function, I have the following function that receives a data.frame as parameter, which can vary widely in the number of rows. I want to print a histogram as image or likeness. The problem is that I always have problems barplot margins. Is there any way to do the same histogram with another library that no problems margins?

function:

```
   HIST_EPC_list<-function(DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter){
    num<-nrow(DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter)
    barplot(DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter$Num_EPC, names.arg = DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter$Tag_PHASE, xlab = "Tag_PHASE", ylab = "Num_EPC", main="Histograma Num tags/PHASE:", width=40)
    par(mar=c(10,10,10,10))
}
```

data.frame example:
DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter

```
 Tag_PHASE Num_EPC
1     123.0       1
2      75.0       1
3      78.0       1
4      81.0       2
5      84.0       1
6      87.0       1
7      90.0       2
8      98.0       1
```

Error:

```
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
Called from: barplot(DF_TAG_RSSI_EPC_counter$Num_EPC, names.arg = DF_TAG_RSSI_EPC_counter$Tag_RSSI, 
    xlab = "Tag_RSSI", ylab = "Num_EPC", main = "Histograma Num tags/RSSI:", 
    width = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you adjusting the `par` settings anywhere?

Comment: yes,par(mar=c(6,6,6,6)), but those values ​​above gives me an error margins. The problem is that the number of rows in the data.frame can vary greatly, as do the Y axis values

Comment: I do not get that error when running with the data above. But if our error is about margins, then it is likely you are not creating a large enough graphics device to write this too. `mar=c(6,6,6,6)` seems a bit extreme. How are you saving the plot?

Comment: I'm using the function inside another using R2HTML plots to save an HTML file. The data.frames that are received by the function are within a list. The problem is that some data.frames can be quite large.

Comment: example of other data.frame:  `Var1 Freq
1  101.0    1
2  120.0    1
3  146.0    1
4   16.0    1
5  163.0    1
6   25.0    1
7   42.0    1
8   53.0    2
9   56.0    1
10  61.0    1
11  64.0    3
12  75.0    1`

Comment: If you want counts of each unique value, and you have too many levels for a plot, consider output the results as a table. Or just make your images much larger.

Comment: Well I need that information out in histogram format. How could I make the barplot out bigger?

Comment: You didn't paste any code where you are actually creating the images so i have no idea what to suggest. Please edit the original question with more information so that others may help.

Comment: Edited, I add par () function